# how to apply a linear gradient on the non transparent part of a png?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to apply a linear-gradient on a png image, I want to apply it only on the non transparent part of but what I get is a linear-gradient on it's whole bounding box

Here is my css:

```
  .MyImage { 
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100%; 
      background: 
         linear-gradient(
            to left, 
            rgba(25, 43, 83, 0.4),
            #182848); 
   }
```

How do I apply it only on non-transparent part ? thanks

**Edit** here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HichamZouarhi/9qwjvgwp/)

Comment: Seems like you need a Photoshop, not CSS. In any case, I've never heard that you can apply a background image to an img tag. PS: A fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: @sdvnksv I edited my question with a jsfiddle, thanks

Comment: You want something like this?
https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/mask-image/